# Error coming while debugging the struts 2 project Any one can fix this

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

Here is an error coming while debugging the Struts2 project:

[image]

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error type Exception report
>
> messageInternal Server Error
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.raj.java.TutorialAction.execute()
>
> note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are
>   available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
>   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1

Can anyone suggest how to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add `execute` method.